# Volume buttons on EarPods activate iPhone screen

Tags: iphone, screen, headphones

When the screen to my iPhone is asleep/deactivate whilst it is playing music, I often adjust the volume using the buttons on the control for my EarPods, but annoyingly this always activates the screen (i.e. lights it up). Is there any way to disable this behaviour?

Comment: What's the model of iPhone you are using and the version of iOS running on it?

Comment: iPhone 8, latest iOS